# What are the sine and cosine of dyadic angles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

What are the values of sine and cosine of [dyadic angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational)? We know
$$\cos\pi = -1 \qquad \cos\frac{\pi}{2} = 0 \qquad \cos\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\,,$$
and we can calculate sine by appealing to symmetry. But I don't think I've seen the sine and cosine values, presented in terms of radicals, of $\pi/8$, $3\pi/8$, $\pi/16$, $\pi/2^n$, etc. Do these have nice algebraic presentations? How can we calculate these?

Comment: OK, I'm having far too much fun with this. Angle-sum formulas, multiple-angle formulas (with complex numbers and de Moivre), half-angle formulas, proof by induction, Gray code.

Comment: @DavidK I'm glad you're having fun with this! The rule for the $+$/$-$ sequence in the radical got _way_ more complicated than I was expecting. Your work on this is cool :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of these expressions are listed on the [Trigonometric constants expressed in real radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals)
 Wikipedia page. But frankly calculating these isn't too bad. Using [the half-angle formula for cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) we can calculate the cosine of principal dyadic angles of the form $\pi/2^n$ as
$$
\cos\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}
\qquad
\cos\frac{\pi}{16} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}
\qquad
\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dotsb\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}
$$
where the last expression has $n-1$ radicals. We can calculate the corresponding sines using the Pythagorean identity; the only difference being that first $+$ under each radical becomes a minus sign. Then for general dyadic angles $m\pi/2^n$, for example $11\pi/16$, we can partition $m$ into powers of $2$, and use the [sum of angles formula for cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), like
$$
\cos\frac{11\pi}{16} = \cos\left(\frac{1+2+8}{16}\pi\right)
=
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
=\dotsb\\\\\dotsb=
\cos\frac{\pi}{16}\cos\frac{\pi}{8}\cos\frac{\pi}{2}
-
\cos\frac{\pi}{16}\sin\frac{\pi}{8}\sin\frac{\pi}{2}
-
\sin\frac{\pi}{16}\cos\frac{\pi}{8}\sin\frac{\pi}{2}
-
\sin\frac{\pi}{16}\sin\frac{\pi}{8}\cos\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and then cleaned up from there. Maybe there's something clever and succinct than can be said about how to express $\cos\frac{m\pi}{2^n}$ combinatorially based on $n$ and the binary partition of $m$. I'm marking this answer CW hoping someone wants to figure that out ;)

---

Also note that if we have the sines an cosines of multiples of $\pi/2^n$
from $0$ to $\pi/4,$ all the other values follow immediately from various trig identities such as
$\sin\left(\frac\pi2 - \theta\right) = \cos(\theta)$ and
$\cos(\pi - \theta) = -\cos(\theta).$

For a complete table of sines and cosines of $\pi/16,$ for example, we only need sines and cosines of $0,$ $\pi/16,$ $\pi/8,$ $3\pi/16,$ and $\pi/4.$

To find $\cos(3\pi/16),$ let's try the half-angle formulas in the forms
$\cos(\theta / 2) = \pm\frac12 \sqrt{2 + 2\cos\theta},$
and $\sin(\theta / 2) = \pm\frac12 \sqrt{2 - 2\cos\theta},$
which are just the usual formulas with a little algebraic manipulation.
We have

\begin{align}
\cos \frac{3\pi}{16}
&= \frac12 \pm\sqrt{2 + 2\cos\frac{3\pi}{8}} \\
&= \frac12 \pm\sqrt{2 + 2\sin\frac\pi8} \\
&= \frac12 \pm\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2-\sqrt2}},
\end{align}

and we can use the fact that $0 < \frac{3\pi}{16} < \frac\pi2$ to conclude that
$$ \cos \frac{3\pi}{16} = \frac12\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}. $$

Similarly we get
$$ \sin \frac{3\pi}{16} = \frac12\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}. $$

At this point a pattern may be seen to be emerging.
Suppose that for a given integer $n\geq2,$ for every odd integer $m$ there is a true formula of the form
$$
2 \cos\frac{m\pi}{2^n} = \pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\cdots\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt2}}}
$$
with $n-1$ radicals on the right-hand side of the equation.
Then
\begin{align}
2 \cos\frac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}
&= \pm\sqrt{2 + 2\cos\frac{m\pi}{2^n}} \\
&= \pm\sqrt{2 \pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\cdots\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt2}}}},
\end{align}
with $n$ radicals on the right side of the final equation.
As a base case we can take $n = 2,$ where we easily confirm that for every odd integer $m,$
$$ 2 \cos \frac{m\pi}{4} = \pm \sqrt2 $$
with $n-1 = 1$ radical on the right-hand side of the equation.
From these facts we can prove the formula for $\cos(m\pi/2^n)$ by induction.
Moreover, we can also show that $\sin(m\pi/2^n)$ has the same formula as $\cos(m\pi/2^n)$ except that the sign of the second radical is reversed
and the sign of the first radical may also be reversed.
So all that remains for filling in a table of sines and cosines is to find the correct signs of each radical in the expressions in each entry in the table.

It is relatively simple to find each entry in the table for multiples of $\pi/2^{n+1}$ by starting with a table for multiples of $\pi/2^n.$
It is of interest to search for an algorithm that gives the correct sequence of signs directly from $m$ and $n$ without generating the intermediate tables.

---

The following is a table of cosines for angles from $0$ to $\frac\pi4$.

\begin{array}{ccc}
\theta  & \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \hline
0  &   1 &  0 \\
\dfrac\pi{64} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac\pi{32} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}} \\
\dfrac{3\pi}{64}
 & \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}
 & \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}  \\
\dfrac\pi{16} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}} \\
\dfrac{5\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac{3\pi}{32} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}  \\
\dfrac{7\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac\pi8 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2} \\
\dfrac{9\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac{5\pi}{32} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}} \\
\dfrac{11\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac{3\pi}{16} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}} \\
\dfrac{13\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}}}  \\
\dfrac{7\pi}{32} &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}} \\
\dfrac{15\pi}{64}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}}
 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}}} \\
\dfrac\pi4 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt2 &  \dfrac12 \sqrt2 \\
\end{array}

If you follow the signs in the formula for the cosines of odd multiples of $\pi/2^n$ in sequence ($\pi/2^n, 3\pi/2^n, 5\pi/2^n, \ldots$),
the signs before the last radical seen to follow the pattern
"negative, positive two times, negative," repeated indefinitely.
Before the second-to-last radical the pattern is
"negative two times, positive four times, negative two times."
And each time you move one place left in the expression,
the length of each part of the repeating pattern doubles.

This same pattern is seen in
[binary reflected Gray code](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GrayCode.html).
To get the sign of the $k$th radical in the expression for $\cos(m\pi/2^n),$
convert the $(n-1)$-bit binary representation of $(m-1)/2$ (padded with zeros on the left) to Gray code using the rule that the $k$th bit of the Gray code is the XOR of the $k$th bit of the binary number and the next bit to the left in the binary number. The resulting bits in order from left to right correspond to the radicals in order from left to right, each radical being positive (resp. negative) if the corresponding Gray code bit is $0$ (resp. $1$).

Another way to put this is, counting radicals from the left,
the sign in front of the $k$th radical is the sign of $2^{k-1} \cos\theta.$
If you also follow the convention that there is no $k$th radical
when $2^{k-1} \cos\theta = 0,$ this rule seems to account both for the length and for all signs within each entry in the cosine column.
This ought to be provable by induction following a similar argument to the one used to show that
$\cos\dfrac{m\pi}{2^n} = \pm\dfrac12\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\cdots\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt2}}}$ for odd $m.$

Answer (score 2):

This answer has some approaches that were not the easiest ways to solve the problem. I'm recording them here in a separate answer so as not to lose the information (even if what this tells us is not to do it this way.)

---

For a complete table of sines and cosines of $\pi/16,$ we only need to compute values for $0,$ $\pi/16,$ $\pi/8,$ $3\pi/16,$ and $\pi/4.$
We already have cosines of all of these (in another answer) except $\cos(3\pi/16).$

Using the angle-sum formula for cosine,

\begin{align}
\cos \frac{3\pi}{16}
&= \cos\frac\pi8 \cos\frac\pi{16} - \sin\frac\pi8 \sin\frac\pi{16} \\
&= \frac14\sqrt{2+\sqrt2} \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
   - \frac14\sqrt{2-\sqrt2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}} \\
\end{align}

It should be possible to simplify this further (see other answer) but the path is not obvious.

---

As an alternative to partitioning $m\pi/2^n$ into powers of two, there are the (somewhat) well-known [formulas for the sine and cosine of arbitrary multiples of angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649717/139123):

\begin{align}
\sin(k\theta) &= \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} \cos^j\theta \, \sin^{n-j}\theta \, \sin\frac{(k-j)\pi}{2}, \\
\cos(k\theta) &= \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} \cos^j\theta \, \sin^{n-j}\theta \, \cos\frac{(k-j)\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

There is [a relatively simple proof](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html) using complex numbers. That may not be a good proof to expect trig students to be able to follow, but it might give some incentive to study complex numbers later.

\begin{align}
\cos \frac{3\pi}{16}
&= \cos^3 \frac{\pi}{16} - 3 \cos \frac{\pi}{16} \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{16} \\
&= \cos \frac{\pi}{16} \left(\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{16} - 3 \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{16} \right) \\
&= \cos \frac{\pi}{16} \left(\frac14\left(2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)
       - \frac34 \left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) \right) \\
&= \cos \frac{\pi}{16} \left(-1 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&= \frac12 \left(-1 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}

Again it should be possible to simplify this further but the path is not obvious.