# Prove that $2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x\right)$ can be expanded as nested radical, where the order of $+,-$ can be described in certain way

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, binary, nested-radicals

I am asked to prove that
$$
2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(s_0\sqrt{2+s_1\sqrt{2+s_2\sqrt{2+\cdots+s_{n-1}\sqrt{2+s_n}}}}\bigg)
$$
for $x\in[-2,2]$, where $\{s_n\}_{n\ge0}\subset\{1,-1\}$ and
$$
x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^j}\prod_{k=0}^js_k
$$
This formula can be seen as a binary-system expansion of $x$. I know a relatively general method for computing the nested radical for $2\sin\theta~~(\theta\in[0,\pi/2])$ by double angle formula, which makes use of
$$
2\sin\theta=\sqrt{2-2\cos2\theta}\\
2\cos\theta=\sqrt{2+2\cos2\theta}\\
$$
over and over again. When $2\theta>\pi$ at some step, minus $\pi$ from $2\theta$ and produce an extra "$-$" seems solve the problem, and the variation of the signal $+,-$ in front of every square root seems exactly to be $\{s_n\}_{n\ge0}$. I can get a taste about the sketch of the proof, but have difficulties handling some of the details. Please help me with that. Thanks a lot!

Later: I might have shown that
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(s_0\sqrt{2+s_1\sqrt{2+s_2\sqrt{2+\cdots+s_{n-1}\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot2^nx\right)}}}}\bigg)
$$
Now it suffices to prove the right side equals to the previous nested radical, which I can not come up with an effective method.

Comment: Related: [Solving finite and infinite nested square roots of 2 - yet another interesting approach](/q/3937457/)

Comment: Essentially, look at $2(s_0x-1)$, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the sine and cosine of dyadic angles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267002/what-are-the-sine-and-cosine-of-dyadic-angles)

Comment: Thank you! These links inspired me a lot, but here i have not assumed that $x$ has the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ for some integer $m,n$, and i can not handle the process of taking limit here.

Comment: So if I understand the question now, you understand the equation for a fixed finite $n$, but not how to prove the limit.

Comment: Actually, i have proved that $\sin(\cdot)$ equals to the limit on the right side of my last equation (since that equation holds for every fixed $n$, so as their limit), but it remains to show that limit equals to the previous nested radical.